# Intellij Idea, Python Plugin - Is Scientific mode available for the Community Edition?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, data-science

I have been using Intellij IDEA (w/ Python Plugin) for quite some time, and I never have heard about the Scientific Mode before today.

Well, it seems an interesting tool for my ML projects but I cannot find it where it in my IDE.

So, the question that stands is: does it exist for the community edition of Intellij IDEA w/ the Python plugin?

Looking forward for your experiences w/ it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is supported in Professional Edition only, please see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/scientific-tools.html

Comment: Thanks. I haven't figured out that Intellij IDEA w/ python plugin would be equivalent to a PyCharm Community Edition.

Answer (score 0):

providing the IDEA version is a community, yes.

If it is Ultimate, then the option should exist https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/matplotlib-support.html

Answer (score 0):

For ML projects, you also have DataSpell from the same editor (JetBrains).

https://www.jetbrains.com/dataspell/